# How to send notifications to an offline member deleted from a chat group?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

I am new to XMPP and working on a group chat application similar to watsapp. The scenario is:

"User A creates a group chat adding users B, C and D to it. All members are online and they are chatting. Now D takes the app to background or kills the app. Now A removes D from the group. How user D will be notified that A has removed him from the group, when D comes back to the app ?

I am using ejabberd (15.11) with PostgreSQL and following the XMPP architecture. I am not sure if the answer is out there, so would like to get help here.

Comment: The description of your question does not seem to match title. Title is about presence, question is about notification of rights change in a group chat. Can you please clarify your question ?

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. The title is misleading. The description posted for the question is the scenario I am stuck with.

Comment: Maybe you should update your post to change your title, then :) Can you also clarify what you mean by A removes D from the group ? Which XMPP packet are you sending is it a member based room ? Do you mean A removes D from member list ?

Comment: Yes. It is member based room. A was the admin and D was the member and he deletes D from the member list.

Answer (score 2):

XMPP MUC specifications says in section [9.5: Modifying the Member List](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#modifymember):

> If a removed member is currently in a members-only room, the service
>   SHOULD kick the occupant by changing the removed member's role to
>   "none" and send appropriate presence to the removed member as
>   previously described. The service MUST subsequently refuse entry to
>   the user.

It means that the participant will only receive his own status change modification if it is present it the room when the event happen. If he is not online at that time, he can only know his credentials has been removed, because he cannot join the room anymore. In other words, in the current state of the specifications, there is no way to get that removal notification when user was not in the room when the removal happened. You can just infer he was removed because he cannot join the room again on next login.

There is nothing else defined in XEP-0045 Multi-User Chat to store membership event for offline participant and later delivery.

Comment: I think I was not clear earlier...let me explain this again. D was not using the app for a while, the app is in background and he is go disconnected from XMPP. Now A removes him from the member list. How I will notify D that he is removed from the group?

Comment: You were clear and I replied to this. In the current state of the specifications, there is no way when user was not in the room to get that removal notification. You can just infer this because he cannot join the room again. If you need to have specifically notification, you need to customize the protocol and the server.